# 'convert' taking a long time to create a PNG thumbnail

Tags: ubuntu, conversion, imagemagick, ghostscript

I made a png from a pdf using ghostscript. It was converted very fast (not more than 1 sec), and has good quality.

```
$ identify 1.png
1.png PNG 3508x2480 3508x2480+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 2c 51KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

But for some reason I have to have a thumbnail for this kind of image.

And I don't know how to make it with `gs`, so I did the thumbnail with the `convert` tool from ImageMagick like this:

```
$ convert -thumbnail 906 1.png t.png
```

Resize takes about 2-4 second. Why? Why is creating the thumbnail taking taking longer than the pdf to big image conversion process? 
Is there any way how to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you get similar results with other images?

Comment: i did not try with other, because they are the same (almost the same). At least their content almost the same.

Comment: When i'm trying to make thumbnail from pdf with help gs, the text in result looks ugly. If i'm trying to get original image from pdf (with -r300) text looks good. I like how fast gs make thumbnails from pdf files, but they looks like not so good ;(